# Problem with the limit of requests api youtube v3 search

Tags: curl, api, youtube

I execute the following command:

```
curl -G https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search \
-d part="id" \
-d q="es-por-ti-juanes" \
-d maxResults="1" \
-d key="..........." \
-d type="video" \
-d videoCaption="none"
```

The problem comes when I launch the command that launches a query of more than 200 queries:

[image]

I need to do about 100 queries and only return a one query and I do not spend the requests to the api I just want to return a one video only I've tried with `maxResults =" 1 "` but I'm still looking for all videos with that name idea???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a YouTube API, and does not appear to be about Unix or Linux.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495998/cli-utility-to-search-and-view-download-youtube-videos/496140#496140). May be of some help.